# How to use (learning data preparations) multilayered perseptron for anomaly detection?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, multi-layer, anomaly-detection

I have a task to use machine learning for anomaly detection.
I have data as sales count info like that:

```
{ 5/*bread*/, 10/*milk*/, 2/*potato*/, .../*other products*/ },
{ 6, 9, 3, ... }, { 5, 12, 1, ... },
{ 10/*bread sales count is anomaly high*/, 10, 2, ... },
{ 4, 8, 3, ... }
```

I coded learning set generator based on idea to turn certain product sales count into array **{ 5, 6, 5, 10, 4, ... }**, calc **mean value** (let's assume it **5**), turn array into percents diff from mean value **{ 0%, 20%, 0%, 100%, -20%, ... }**, so if array does not contains values higher by module than 5%, then there is no anomalies in row. I know I can use simplest self-made functionc to check this, but I **HAVE** a task to use machine learning for that.

My generator were making sequences like { 1%, 3%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...} and were labeling them as **good**. That way it made around 1k good sequences.
After this generator starts to generate **anomal** sequences by modifing **good** ones into this: `{ 24%, 3%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ... }, { -24%, 3%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...}, { 1%, 24%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ... }, { 1%, -24%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...}, ..., { 1%, 3%, -2%, 5%, -100% }`

Later I transformed this percents into [0, 1] range and fed to multilayer perceptron with 128 neurons in second layer, 32 in third and 2 in output (good or anomaly). After learning I got around **50%** recognition rate that is terribly bad.

Then I modified my generator to generate 1k **good** sequences like that **{ 1%, 3%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...}** and 1k **bad** sequences like that **{ 25%, 50%, -60%, 40%, -80%, ...}**. The recognition rate still were around **50%**.

Which way is possible to generate learning set, so later network will tell that **{ 1%, 3%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...}** is **good** and any of **{ 1%, -24%, -2%, 5%, 1%, ...}** is **bad**?

Comment: How do you train MLP?

Comment: @viceriel - I don't know... I use tensorflow for this. And that same network does fine recognition for MNIST, so there is problem with my learning sets.